# Are Function in static libs, that are not exposed in a header, accessible?

Tags: c

I understand a compiler error will be generated if no prototype for the function is found. But lets say I knew that a library contained some non-public function, and I created my own prototype for it (matching the one inside the static lib), would the linker be able to pull this in?

The reason I'm asking is I am creating a library where I'm using common generic names for functions, like "init()", that are only for internal use. I'm wondering if they would collide with symbols outside of the library during linking

Answer (score 5):

Its depends on the linkage of the function:

```
//.c file

// external linkage, accessible from outside using the right prototype
void foo(void) {}

// internal linkage, not accessible from outside
static void bar(void) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I have a function in one file that I want to be accessible by only one other file, but nothing else. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: @BrandonYates You can't do this in C.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is for the benefit of the compiler, not the linker. The compiler will happily compile the code for any function that you declare, but you'll get a linker error if you try to use a function that is defined as static in another file or library.

You can, and should, declare your own functions as static if they're not to be used outside of the file. But if you then compile with other code that contains declarations with identical function names, you'll get conflicts unless they're all defined identically. For example, if you defined your `init` function as static, it would be available directly only in that file; but if you included any header file that declared another function differently with the name `init`, you'd get an error.

(It is possible to access static functions in another file, but it requires pointers.)

Comment: If you link several files all defining the same name `static` nothing happens, the `static` makes the name have file scope (i.e., invisible elsewhere).

Comment: @vonbrand: assuming that the different functions are declared, you'll get an error with mismatched declarations. Unless I guess all the identical function names are defined in exactly the same way.

Comment: Go try. You'll see that your `static double foo(double)` in `a.c` is totally independent from `static int foo` in `b.c` and `static unsigned long foo(int, char *)` in `c.c`. If not, your C stack is horribly broken, get a decent operating system.

Comment: @vonbrand That's fine, as long as you don't include a declaration of them. e.g. if a.c includes a prototype for b.c's static foo as well as declaring its own, it'll result in a compiler error.

Comment: I just tried it: `asdf.c:3:12: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’`

Comment: Why would you want to declare a function that can't be used?

Comment: If it's contained in a header file. If you declared your `foo` as static in `a.c` but included a header from another file that also declares a `foo` you'd get this error, whether it's static or not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to define some prefix for your library, e.g. `ouah_` and give all functions/variables names prefixed by it, unless you can make them `static` (i.e., visible only in the file in which they are defined). No, it won't *ensure* there aren't name collisions, but it should reduce them a lot. Like the reason behind Doug Gwin's [Q8](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/q8/index.html)...

This BTW is the reason behing the `namespace` thing in C++, and also in part to blame for OOP and its "methods"/"member functions" belonging to "classes"